# Real Centroids plugin QGis 3.4.4 Inavlid Geometry?

Tags: qgis-plugins, centroids

The plugin gives on a specific feature the following error message:
"Invalid or empty geometries found".
Is the following topology not supported?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please explain your issue in detail..as your error looks like some objects have missing geometries that why your are getting this error. Please check your feature properly

Comment: There are two ways to make a polygon like that. Either with just the outer ring that touches itself at one point. This is the ESRI way and it is invalid according to OGC Simple Feature model. The SF way is to have an outer ring and an inner ring that makes a hole. You may have an ESRI style polygon.

Comment: Try to run Fix geometries first. PostGIS has a special ESRI flag  https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html but QGIS does not seem to have that option.

Comment: Thank you all, I think user30184 adresses the issue. It is a ESRI style polygon with an inner ring which touches the outer ring at one point. Check validity reports no errors.
What surprise me that Real Centroids crashes, there are 302 features and only one has this topology. Now it was not easy to find the invalid one.

Comment: The standard Centroids function of QGis gives the same error:
Feature (183) has invalid geometry.